# Ebpf modify whole packet data

Tags: c, pointers, packet, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I am using XDP and trying to modify `ctx->data`.
Let's say for this example, I want to set all the packet bytes to x+3 (x is a byte from the packet).
Is that possible? I tried the following code and got errors from the verifier:

```
int xdp_start(struct xdp_md* ctx)
{
    void* data = (void*)(long)ctx->data;
    void* data_end = (void*)(long)ctx->data_end;
    uint32_t length = data_end - data;
    void* temp_data = data;
    size_t i = 0;
    #pragma unroll
    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if ((__u8*)temp_data > (__u8*)data_end)
            break;
        *(__u8*)temp_data += (__u8)2;
        temp_data++;
     }
     return XDP_PASS;
}
```

It failed with “pointer arithmetic on pkt_end prohibited”

I also changed the for loop to:

```
for (i=0; i < length && i < 1500; i++)
```

To satisfy the verifier and make sure that this is not an infinite loop there is a way to not do that?

Also, I tried to set all packet bytes to a constant number:

```
*(__u8*)temp_data = 2;
```

And the verifier failed with:

> A call to built-in function ‘memset’ is not supported.

When did I call memset?

In summary, I want to change each byte on the packet into another byte, is that possible? If yes I will be happy to know how.

Comment: `void* data = (void*)(long)ctx->data;`?  Pointers aren't guaranteed to fit in `long`.  And given `void* temp_data`, you can't do `temp_data++;` because pointer arithmetic can't be done on `void *` pointers.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `ctx->data` is on 32-bits in BPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help!
I used Andrew and pchaigno advice and the verifier still reject my program.
Then I understood that my problem also was that I was incremented the pointer without checking it.

```
int xdp_start(struct xdp_md* ctx)
{
    void* data = (void*)(long)ctx->data;
    void* data_end = (void*)(long)ctx->data_end;
    uint32_t length = data_end - data;
    void* temp_data = data;
    size_t i = 0;
    #pragma unroll
    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if ((__u8*)temp_data + 1 > (__u8*)data_end)
            break;
        *(__u8*)temp_data += (__u8)2;
        (__u8*)temp_data++;
     }
     return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Notice the change in the if, It should be + 1. Maybe the verifier does not even like that there is a variable that points to an out of bounds area.

Answer (score 2):

> It failed with “pointer arithmetic on pkt_end prohibited”

As Andrew said in comments, you'll first have to declare `temp_data` as a `__u8*` to be able to run `temp_data++`.

> To satisfy the verifier and make sure that this is not an infinite loop there is a way to not do that?

No, all loops have to have bounds known at compile time in BPF.

> When did I call memset?

Check the compiled bytecode. Your compiler likely used `memset` for you, as an optimization for the loop.